# Timestamp to 12 HR Format (HH:MM AM?PM)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can I convert this one to 12 Hour Format?

`Sun Dec 31 14:45:42 GMT+07:36 1899`

like this (Ex.)

`2:00 PM`

Comment: Do you have a string or a Date object? There are many, many questions here about [*formatting Dates*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) and reformatting date strings.

Comment: This is a date object sir

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) and the title should be "How to format a Date as hh:mm ap" or similar. A timestamp is a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an answer that is specific to Google Apps Script, the most simple fix I can think of is to change the way you define the formatting. Based on the title of this ticket I assume you're using this:

```
var date = new Date("Sun Dec 31 14:45:42 GMT+07:00 1899");

var date_24hr = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+7:00', 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zXX yyyy'); 
// logs Sun Dec 31 14:45:42 GMT+07:00 1899

var date_12hr = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+7:00', 'EEE MMM dd h:mm:ss a zXX yyyy'); 
// logs Sun Dec 31 02:45:42 PM GMT+07:00 1899

var time_12hr = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+7:00', 'h:mm a'); 
// logs 02:45 PM
```

The key is to use lowercase `h` instead of capital `H` in the formatDate value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date(); 

function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

formatAMPM(date);
```

Comment: @kindly check now, And tell me.

Comment: what do u mean sir about the text

Comment: is this working??? i am sending date object to function and it will return 12 hrs format.

Comment: "*Here is the date object we have…*", no, that is a string representation of the date.

Comment: Ohhoo,
That is the comment man, i just added to this for more information.
now check it. I think now it is more clear to everyone

Comment: Apparently the OP has a Date object, in which case this is a duplicate.

Comment: still not working sir, the new Date removes the time in TimeStamp

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this as a GAS question, have you looked at `Utilities.formatDate()`? Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), but in short it takes 3 parameters: a date object, a time-zone string & a format string. The TZ & format are taken from the [Java SE SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

In your instance, try this:

```
var d = new Date("Sun Dec 31 14:45:42 GMT+07:36 1899");
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+07:00", "h:mm a")); // logs 2:09 PM
```